# Generic type parameter is array - how to instantiate and copy?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I have a generic class where the type parameter (T) is known to be an array, e.g. int[]. The class has a property of type T with both a setter and a getter.
When setting the propery a shallow copy of the source array should be made, i.e. storing the reference is not good enough. When instantiating the class the length of the array is known.

1. When setting the property I could just clone the source array and store the result, however I think I would like to have pre-allocated storage and do a shallow copy of the source array. I know cloning would probably be a cleaner approach, but I would like to try to avoid excessive creation of objects. How do I create an array of type T of a given size in the constructor of my class?
2. In the setter, how do I copy the content of the source array to my pre-allocated storage?

(I think) I have created a working example of what I would like to achieve, however I hope there must be a nicer solution.

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    T value;

    public MyClass(int length)
    {
        this.value = (T)(object)Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T).GetElementType(), length);
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)((ICloneable)this.value).Clone();
        }

        set
        {
            if(!System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this.value, value))
            {
                var thisArray = this.value as Array;
                ((System.Collections.ICollection)value).CopyTo(thisArray, 0);
                // Expensive operation perfomed here, hence only copy when needed.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `T[] value;` ... `value = new T[length]`?

Comment: @CodeCaster T is an array type, e.g. int[], hence your proposal would leave me with a two-dimensional array in this case.

Comment: I think CodeCaster is proposing a simpler solution; using `T[] value;` means instantiating your class like this: `var instance = new MyClass<int>(5);` instead of like this: `var instance = new MyClass<int[]>(5);`